# What semantic notions underlie 人 (person) and 僅 (solely)?

Tags: etymology

[CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%83%85) and [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?searchChinese=1&zi=%E5%83%85) don't expound the semantic shift. I'm especially addled by the shift in lexical categories too, from a noun to an adverb.

> Synopsis  : 從「[人](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BA%BA)」，「[堇](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A0%87)」聲，用作副詞，表示才、只。
>
> Elaboration: 從「[人](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%BA%BA)」，「[堇](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%A0%87)」聲，用作副詞，表示才、只。《說文》：「材能也。从人，堇聲。」《國語‧周語中》：「今天降災於周室，余一人僅能守府。」
>
> 「[僅](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%83%85)」也指數量少。《公羊傳‧恆公三年》：「此其曰有年何？僅有年也。彼其曰大有年何?大豐年也。」何休注：「僅，猶劣也，謂五穀多少皆有，不能大成熟。」

[image]

Comment: It seems you are trying to find semantic connections for a phonetic component, or am I misunderstanding your question? It says in both your quoted entries that 堇 gives the sound, so why are you looking for a semantic relationship?

Comment: @OlleLinge I'm asking about the Semantic (not Phonetic) Component, 人.

Answer (score 3):

*Outlier*

> 1 (orig.) ability, talent
> 2 ○ only

Here the ○ icon is an indicator of a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Rebus_(phonetic_loan)_characters). So, basically it is just a:

> character that is "borrowed" to write another homophonous or near-homophonous morpheme